# How to split text by lines

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript, mxml

Flex 3.

I created a TextArea object. Then I typed some text in it. Then i got this text useing TextArea.text property.

How can I split text I got by lines and convert it to the array of strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "\n" doesn't work for you, try "\r" (carriage return).  Here's some code demonstrating how it'd work -- just type into the box and you'll see the array contents change:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" creationComplete="onCreationComplete(event)">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import mx.events.CollectionEvent;
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            [Bindable]
            private var ac:ArrayCollection;

            protected function onCreationComplete(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                ac = new ArrayCollection();
                ac.addEventListener(CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE, onCollectionChange);     
            }

            protected function onKeyUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void
            {
                ac.source = event.target.text.split("\r");
            }

            protected function onCollectionChange(event:CollectionEvent):void
            {
                contents.text = ac.source.join("\r");           
            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:TextArea id="input" x="19" y="22" width="273" height="175" keyUp="onKeyUp(event)" />
    <mx:TextArea id="contents" x="112" y="249" width="180" height="175" editable="false" />
    <mx:Label x="19" y="222" text="Array Length:" fontWeight="bold" />
    <mx:Label x="37" y="250" text="Contents:" fontWeight="bold" />
    <mx:Label x="111" y="222" text="{ac.length}" />

</mx:Application>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

What does "split by lines" mean to you?  The usual thing is to scan the text for the last blank before textwidth, and call that a line.

Comment: i need to convert multiline text into the array of Strings, where each element is separate line(string of text?)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this site](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=textcontrols_03.html), the character for a line feed feed is "\n".  Using the Split() function with "\n" you should be able to split the string into an array of string separated by line feeds.

Comment: it was my first thought to solve this problem this way. But it doesn't work!